# Dependencies issues in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 16.04, 18.04

I just recently changed my partition sizes on Windows 10. It worked well...but I have Ubuntu installed also and I am having issues with it. 
When I boot to Ubuntu OS, every time I am getting a popup dialogue box saying some dependencies are not installed or missing. Here's the screenshot:

[image: screen]

I tried to install Network package manually with `sudo apt-get install network-manager` but with that, I am getting `network-manager is already the newest version (1.10.6-2ubuntu1.1).`.
I don't know how to manually install the other two.

Comment: You should be doing `sudo apt install -f`to try and fix that message!

Comment: I can see there are two packages. One have `network-manager` in its name but it is not exactly network-manager. Try installing those mentioned packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please run the following to fix that issue:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -f
sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: Why don't you run update before install -f? I think the correct way is to fetch packages index first and the try to recover missing stuff.

Comment: Yes that's true but sometimes that's not necessary as the system has done so previously.

Comment: the upgrade did the job done.